# Python Deleting Multiple Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to delete certain repeating lines from a file I have. I am using the following code but it doesn't seem to work. There are no error messages just nothing has been deleted in the output file. I've attached the code below and a sample out what part of the file i'm trying to change looks like. Anyone able to help?

CODE:

```
infile = "angles"
outfile = "angles_1.txt"

delete_list = ["""ITEM: TIMESTEP
0
ITEM: NUMBER OF ENTRIES
18
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0 250
0 250
0 250
ITEM: ENTRIES c_11[1] c_11[2] c_11[3] c_11[4] c_22"""]
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

FILE I WANT TO CHANGE:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
0
ITEM: NUMBER OF ENTRIES
18
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0 250
0 250
0 250
ITEM: ENTRIES c_11[1] c_11[2] c_11[3] c_11[4] c_22 
1 2 3 1 180 
2 3 4 1 180 
3 4 5 1 180 
4 5 6 1 180 
5 6 7 1 180 
6 7 8 1 180 
7 8 9 1 180 
8 9 10 1 180 
9 10 11 1 180 
10 11 12 1 180 
12 13 14 1 180 
11 12 13 1 180 
15 16 17 1 180 
14 15 16 1 180 
13 14 15 1 180 
18 19 20 1 180 
17 18 19 1 180 
16 17 18 1 180 
ITEM: TIMESTEP
1000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ENTRIES
18
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0 250
0 250
0 250
ITEM: ENTRIES c_11[1] c_11[2] c_11[3] c_11[4] c_22 
2 3 4 1 154.251
```

and it continues like this for a couple hundred repeats.

Comment: Your delete_list contains exactly one item. However this item consists of multiple lines (ie. contains newlines) and therefore you'll NEVER find it in a single line

Comment: What do you want to delete? Can you give an output sample of the file how you want it. Replacing the words with "" is not the correct way of deleting.

Comment: I would like the above to look like

1 2 3 1 180 
2 3 4 1 180 
3 4 5 1 180 
4 5 6 1 180 
5 6 7 1 180 
6 7 8 1 180 
7 8 9 1 180 
8 9 10 1 180 
9 10 11 1 180 
10 11 12 1 180 
12 13 14 1 180 
11 12 13 1 180 
15 16 17 1 180 
14 15 16 1 180 
13 14 15 1 180 
18 19 20 1 180 
17 18 19 1 180 
16 17 18 1 180 
2 3 4 1 154.251

Comment: @charlescoj file iteration is line-by-line, but you're checking against a multi-line item. It's never going to match.

Comment: @charlescoj, please add the expected output to your question instead of in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

you have created a list with one element, but I suspect you want a list with many elements, one per line.
Create it like so:

```
delete_list = """ITEM: TIMESTEP
0
ITEM: NUMBER OF ENTRIES
18
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0 250
0 250
0 250
ITEM: ENTRIES c_11[1] c_11[2] c_11[3] c_11[4] c_22""".split("\n")
```

Then in your for loop (`for line in fin`) just check if the entire line matches, if it doesn't then you write it to `fout` otherwise you skip it.

```
if line.strip() not in delete_list:
    fout.write(line)
```

Comment: You should use `split("\n")` and only delete entire lines (so not use `replace()`) otherwise you're likely to delete unwanted parts (e.g. "18" is one of the words it actually appears in lines you don't want to delete).

Comment: as @dirkgroten says, use `.split("\n")` to only delete complete lines - I misunderstood originally, sorry.

Comment: @dirkgroten could you be a bit more explicit please? Just to make sure I understand

How shall I change the replace() section?

Answer (score 1):

Do this if your file is not that big. Read the whole file and replace the part as string.

```
infile = "angles"
outfile = "angles_1.txt"

delete_string = """ITEM: TIMESTEP
0
ITEM: NUMBER OF ENTRIES
18
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0 250
0 250
0 250
ITEM: ENTRIES c_11[1] c_11[2] c_11[3] c_11[4] c_22"""

fin = open(infile).read()
fin = fin.replace(delete_string, '')
fout = open(outfile, "w")
fout.write(fin)
```

Comment: So this deleted the string once at the start but the rest of repeats of it are still there